# Changing a form input to the current time [jquery]

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form with an input that contains the date in the form: 12:00:59 am, 25 December 2010

The most likely time I'd want to change this to is the current time.

Is it possible to have a button or link next to the input field that when clicked jquery would update the time to the current time.

(I'm already using jquery for something else so thought it'd be easier to append a bit more code to my js file than code from scratch)

I can't do this. Here's the html:

```
<form>
    ...
    <p>Time: <input name="time" id="time" type="text" size="30" value="<?php echo $date; ?>"><a href="" name="time-update">Update to now</a></p>
    ...
</form>
```

And heres the JS:

```
$("a[time-update]").click(function(event) {
    var time = Date();
    $("#time").value = time;
    event.preventDefault();
} );
```

It just reloads the page.

Answer (score 2):

Add a click method to the button or link that will set the value of the form using a string gotten from the [JavaScript Date object](http://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_obj_date.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Because it probably throws an exception, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("a[time-update]").click(function(event) {

    var time = new Date();
    $("#time").val(time);
    event.preventDefault();

  });

});
```

hope it helps, Sinan.